# Set initial value of a Date Picker using Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uidatepicker

I have created two datepickers in which the user can enter their desired date and time.

[image: image of the datepickers]

When the user clicks the save button, the entered values are saved into Core Data using the following code:

```
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle

    let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    timeFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
    timeFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

    dateOfEntry = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(entryDate.date)  //entryDate is the name of the IBOutlet of the first date picker.

    timeStarted = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(startTime.date)  //startTime is the name of the IBOutlet of the second date picker.
```

This saves the date as : Nov 4, 2015
And the time as: 11:15 AM
Which I then save into Core Data using

```
 entry.setValue(dateOfEntry, forKey: "date")

 entry.setValue(timeStarted, forKey: "startTime")
```

I was wondering if it is possible for me to use these stored values to later set the initial values of a separate set date pickers when the user opens a different view controller.

Comment: Why not? Retrieve the dates from your managed object, and update your date pickers on `viewDidLoad`. What is not working?

Comment: I am not sure how to update the date pickers. @Mundi

Comment: `datePicker.date = someDate`. You should be able to find that in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you're taking date and time selections that people have made with the picker and converting these to a string, and saving in your core data model as two strings.

A possible problem with this approach is that `stringFromDate` uses local settings on the device (country, language) to format that string, so for example people running the app in the US will have a different format than people in Germany.

Probably what you want to do is combine the selections from your date picker and your time picker into a single `NSDate`, and then save that combined date directly in core data.

It's a little bit more work upfront when you're creating the entity, but you get some benefits:

- don't have to worry about locales from different regions
- if you ever wanted you can now apply sorting of values based on your date attribute
- makes it a lot easier to populate your pickers based off a date returned from a query.